# Autodesk Forge - Reality Capture Issue - Specified Photoscene ID doesn't exist in the database

Tags: node.js, axios, multipartform-data, autodesk-forge, autodesk-realitycapture

i'm trying to upload my files as form-data, after i've created a scene. But I receive always the error "Specified Photoscene ID doesn't exist in the database" (which were created directly before).

My upload function:

```js
// Upload Files
async function uploadFiles(access_Token, photoSceneId, files) {
    try {

        const params = new URLSearchParams({
            'photosceneid': photoSceneId,
            'type': 'image',
            'file': files
        })

        const headers = Object.assign({
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_Token,
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }, 
            files.getHeaders()
        )
        
        let resp = await axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/photo-to-3d/v1/file',
            headers: headers,
            data: params

        })
        let data = resp.data;
        return data;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};
```

I've also tried a few varaints, e.g. adding the photosceneId to the form data (form.append(..), but doesn't works either.

Any helpful suggestion are appreciated. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There might be two problems here.
First, I am not sure of it, as I don't have experience of URLSearchParams as a  "packer" for POST requests. This might be the reason why you get "Specified Photoscene ID doesn't exist in the database" error - perhaps the way the data are serialized using URLSearchParams is not compatible.

The second problem, I am sure of it, is regarding the way you submit the files.
According [to documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/reality-capture/v1/reference/http/file-POST/), you have to pass the files one by one, like

```
  "file[0]=http://www.autodesk.com/_MG_9026.jpg" \
  "file[1]=http://www.autodesk.com/_MG_9027.jpg"
```

and not just passing an array to the "file" field.

Having this said, try this approach:

```js
var axios = require('axios');
var FormData = require('form-data');
var fs = require('fs');
var data = new FormData();
var TOKEN = 'some TOKEN';
const photoSceneID = 'some_photoscene_id';

data.append('photosceneid', photoSceneID);
data.append('type', 'image');
data.append('file[0]', fs.createReadStream('/C:/TEMP/Example/DSC_5427.JPG'));
data.append('file[1]', fs.createReadStream('/C:/TEMP/Example/DSC_5428.JPG'));
data.append('file[2]', fs.createReadStream('... and so on ...'));

var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/photo-to-3d/v1/file',
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + TOKEN, 
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Also, I always recommend instead of jumping right into the code, to check first the workflow using apps like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) or [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) and then, after you validated the workflow (created the photoscene, all images were properly uploaded and so on), you can translate this into the code.

At the end of [this blogpost](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/hitchhikers-guide-reality-capture-api) you will find the link to alrady created Postman collection, but I highly recommend building your own collection, as part of the learning step.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your help. It was actually the problem that I used the URLParams as packer. On the other hand I had not considered the "photosceneid" and the "type" in the FormData. 

Thanks again for the help & happy new year!

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me. Please note that the upload should be limited by a maximum of 20 files per call.

```js
// Upload Files
async function uploadFiles(access_Token, photoSceneId) {
    try {

        let dataPath = path.join(__dirname, '../../data')
        let files = fs.readdirSync(dataPath)
    
        var data = new FormData();

        data.append('photosceneid', photoSceneId)
        data.append('type', 'image')

        for(let i=0; i < files.length; i++) {

            let filePath = path.join(dataPath, files[i])
            let fileName = 'file[' + i + ']'

            data.append(fileName, fs.createReadStream(filePath))
            
        }

        const headers = Object.assign({
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_Token,
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;boundary=' + data.getBoundary()}, 
            data.getHeaders()
        )
        
        let resp = await axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/photo-to-3d/v1/file',
            headers: headers,
            maxContentLength: Infinity,
            maxBodyLength: Infinity,
            data: data

        })
        let dataResp = resp.data;
        return dataResp;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};
```